# Editing ListView Text

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am working on an android app, currently i have following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:textSize="20pt"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;
    private MediaPlayer player = null; 
    ListView listV;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.display_result);
        listV = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final Intent i = new Intent(this,BActivity.class);


         String[] values = new String[] { "C 2 F", "F 2 C", "Currency"};

         ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

         listV.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

         listV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

              int itemPosition     = position;

              if(itemPosition == 0)
              {
                i.putExtra("identify", "c2f");
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                if(player != null)
                    player.stop();
              }
              else if(itemPosition == 1)
              {
                  i.putExtra("identify", "f2c");
                  startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                  if(player != null)
                      player.stop();
              }
              else if(itemPosition == 2)
              {
                  i.putExtra("identify", "currency");
                  startActivityForResult(i, 1);
                  if(player != null)
                      player.stop();
              }


             }

        }); 
    }
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        player.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

          if (requestCode == 1) {
             if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
                 String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
                 tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 tv.setText(result);

                 player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
                 player.start();
             }

          }
        }

}
```

It's all working well, but the ListView is showing very small black text alligned left, i want to change it to center and increase the size, also is there any simple way to include pictures along with text on the listview. I searched on it a lot but they are all extremely difficult to understand, kindly tell me what changes do i have to make in my code to be able to edit the listView text.

Comment: you will need to use a custom layout with a textview

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRANgDgM2Zg check this tutorial out. You need to create a layout for list item then write your own adapter. This tutorial cover the basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need have another layout with `TextView`. Customize the below layout to suit your needs. You can increase the text size change the text color and customize the textview the way you want.

**row.xml.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.textView1, values);
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: error in R.layout.row, row cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @AbdulJabbar you need to have a layout by the name row under `res/layout/row.xml`. Pls read the answer in full top to bottom

Comment: can you please give me the link from where i can copy paste row.xml file code?

Comment: @AbdulJabbar its there in my post. cna't you see the layout posted in my code?. Do you see or you blind?

Comment: oh, i'm really sorry, i was copying that in activity_main.xml

Comment: @AbdulJabbar there is no need to change `activity_main.xml`. just create `row.xml` under `res/layout` and copy paste the above code

Comment: @AbdulJabbar you can use a compound textview or you a custom adapter. google search for custom adapter with image and textview you will n number of examples

Comment: thanks a lot! you're a life saver! one more thing please, is there any way to include the images along with text as well, without going into inflator and extending arrayadaptor class?

Answer (score 1):

All the layout of the ListView is given by the Adapter. You're using the simple ArrayAdapter, with the simple_list_item_1 (that is a simple TextView).

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
```

The good: this is really easy, as you have seen.
The bad: you cannot do much except a list of strings.

If you want to include images, more TextViews or other nice things you will have to create a custom Adapter, overriding the ArrayAdapter or another one, as the BaseAdapter.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) you can find a simple tutorial by Vogella.

As you can see all the work is done in the getView method, where all the "creation" takes place.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    // change the icon for Windows and iPhone
    String s = values[position];
    if (s.startsWith("iPhone")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

At the beginning you will have to "inflate" (create) the row. From the row then you will "find" the views and set the items respectively on the position of the row.

Performance note:

since Android will recycle the rows, you should check if the line was already created. So just check, before the inflate and wrapping all the code, if the convertView is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your **row.xml** with ImageView and TextView . It's a way your list items will look.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/item_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>        
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_image"
            android:id="@+id/item_label"/>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you need to create custom adapter, e.g. `ArrayAdapter` of `String`:

```
public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public SampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_deals_list_fragment, data);
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        String item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffaa66cc")));
        viewHolder.textView.setText(item);
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_label);
        }
    }
}
```

After that do something like this in yout Activity class:

```
SampleAdapter sampleAdapter = new SampleAdapter(this, new String[]{"lorem", "ipsum", "dolar"});
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
listView.setAdapter(sampleAdapter);
```

As result your ListView item will look like an Fill Colored Image and Text.